# Vue.js - Element UI - Dialog with nested Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a VUE JS component with a button that well calls on a dialog with a nested Component. The dialog doesn't work on click, if we change the value of the sync on load to be true it works.
Here is my snippet...

```
    <div>
        <el-button type="success" @click="myModal = true" size="mini">Add User</el-button>
        <input type="hidden" :name="kuku" v-model="kuku">
    </div>


    <div class="">
        <el-dialog :visible.sync="myModal" width="100%" :show-close="false" :close-on-click-modal="false">
            <add-form></add-form>
        </el-dialog>
    </div>
```

need help calling the dialog on click....

Comment: share the code of el-dialog component
The problem is inside that code.

Comment: @JaskaranSingh here  https://jsfiddle.net/mukolweke/epmryt1x/1/

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, I can't see any reference to `visible` in the fiddle you provided.

Comment: you have shared the code of add-form i am asking for el-dialog component.

Comment: el-dialog is a vuejs tag...no code on my part...

Comment: thanks guys but i have found a solution; instead of using a map getter to change the state of visible in store i am now using a method to make change from false to true to the visible state; https://jsfiddle.net/mukolweke/epmryt1x/10/